# Applescript to chop specific text out of a text file and paste it to notes file

Tags: applescript, automator, pdf, text

I have created a text file from a pdf using automator.  I am now trying to copy two separate slices of this file and paste them to a Notes file.  Here is a sample file:

A lot of text above............
1.31 COMMENTS
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  -- Text I want to grab.
1.32 RECOMMENDATIONS
More text below............

More text above............
3.31 COMMENTS
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 2  -- Second lot of text I want to grab.
3.32 RECOMMENDATIONS
A lot more text below..........

I am a complete novice so I have tried several snippets of code found on this site but not much works yet.

This is the closest so far:

```
set theFile to "/Users/UserName/Desktop/Text.txt"
set theFileContents to read theFile as text

set output to ""
set od to AppleScript's text item delimiters

if "1.31 COMMENTS" is in theFileContents then
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"1.31 COMMENTS"}
    set latterPart to last text item of theFileContents
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" "}
    repeat with theWord in latterPart
        if the first character in theWord is "¬" then exit repeat
        set output to output & theWord
    end repeat
else
    display alert "1.31 COMMENTS not found"
    set output to theFileContents
end if

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to od
return output
```

It deletes all the text above "1.31 Comments" ready for copying but nothing else.  I am pretty sure this is not the best option anyway. Anybody help please?

Now this is a bit more like it...

```
set theFile to "/Users/username/Desktop/test.txt"
set theFileContents to read theFile as text

set AddressStartPosition to offset of "Random Company Ltd" in theFileContents

set AddressEndPosition to offset of "Hampshire" in theFileContents

set FirstPosition to offset of "1.31 Comments" in theFileContents

set SecondPosition to offset of "1.32 Recommendations" in theFileContents

set ThirdPosition to offset of "3.31 Comments" in theFileContents

set ForthPosition to offset of "3.32 Recommendations" in theFileContents

set Address to (characters (AddressStartPosition + 28) thru (AddressEndPosition - 1) of theFileContents) as string
set FirstPageComments to (characters FirstPosition thru (SecondPosition - 1) of theFileContents) as string
set ThirdPageComments to (characters ThirdPosition thru (ForthPosition - 1) of theFileContents) as string



set FullText to Address & FirstPageComments & ThirdPageComments


display dialog FullText
```

Just got to deliver it it to the notes file now.

Can someone help me with getting the file name please.  Currently, each time I run the script above I have to manually change the filename in the line below:

```
  set theFile to "/Users/username/Desktop/test.txt"
```

Ideally, I want to be able to right click the file in Finder and then run the script from the Services sub menu.  Is that possible please?